# TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestContent' of undefined for JQuery cdn

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

im using jquery cdn with popper and bootstrap js. The jquery function is to get data from the user, and ajax with POST it to my php code on top. But in the browser console log I am getting a weird warning and error; **TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestContent' of undefined**. However, the a similar type code in another php file works perfectly, what am I doing wrong in this one? The images below are the exact errors im seeing in the console.

1. Console log
   [image: Console log]
2. Error shown in log
   [image: Error shown in log]
3. Network response failed
   [image: Network response failed]

My script codes:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#registerBtn").on('click', function () {
                var classnamed = $("#addclass").val();
               

                if (classnamed != "" ) {
                    $.ajax({
                      url: "classd.php",
                      method: "POST",
                      dataType: "text",
                       data: {addclass: 1, classname: classnamed, code: 'der42'}, 
                       success:function(response){
                          console.log(response);
                        } 
                        
                    });
                } else
                  alert('Please Check Your Inputs');
            });
      });
```

Php code(which is in the same php file):

```
    <?php 
    
    include('server.php');
    
    if (isset($_POST['addclass'])) {
      
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['classname']);
    $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['code']);
          
    
    $db->query("INSERT INTO class (class_code, class_name) VALUES ('$code','$name')");
       
    exit($name);
    }
    ?>
```

If anybody could give an insight to whats going on, that would be great!

Comment: I don't see how that error could be coming from the code you posted.

Comment: I'm having this same issue